# Reference a table from a scalar UDF - tied to schema name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

Due to the rollout/architecture of our system, I would like to create a scalar UDF to use within a `SELECT` statement in a stored procedure

Because our various DEV/TEST/LIVE environments have different schema names, I would ideally like to name my UDF as dbo.MyFunctionName, HOWEVER, because my function contains logic that uses a `SELECT` statement to get values from a database table to return the answer which means I cannot use dbo but must put it under the schema of the database (ie: TEST)  ***NOTE - this is right, right?***

When calling the function from a `SELECT` statement, you must provide the two-part name, so I must use TEST.MyFunctionName

```
SELECT Name, Age, TEST.MyFunctionName(PersonID) FROM People
```

Is there a way to parameterise the schema name so that when I roll it out to different schema, I do not need to create the function under each one and/or amend how it is called? Ideally, I'm looking for something like

```
SELECT Name, Age, SCHEMA_NAME().MyFunctionName(PersonID) FROM People
```

but I'd like to NOT use Dynamic SQL if possible

Many thanks

Comment: Putting scalar functions like that in a select list is a recipe for horrible performance. In general you should try to avoid scalar functions as there are almost always more efficient ways to doing the same thing. Inline table valued functions (iTVF) are one of the most common ways of replacing scalar udfs.

Comment: Sean, is an iTVF just creating a function that returns a table and then joining it to my SELECT statement? I'm trying to optimise a system that pretty much already creates a temp table of ALL the values regardless of if the SELECT statement returns 1, 100 or 1000 results. Or is an iTVF a little more dynamic?

Comment: A scalar-valued function prevents the optimizer from creating a parallel plan and has bad effects on cardinality estimation as well. In plain English: I have never seen a query that didn't execute faster if you replaced the scalar function with an inline table-valued function, so it's certainly worth a try. For simple functions that return one value, use `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen - my function has logic other than just the SELECT statement though. All the articles I've read about ITVF show the RETURN AS RETURN(SELECT...) and I need to do more logic prior to what I return. Is this approach still valid for me?

Comment: No, an inline TVF must be written as a single `SELECT` statement, with no procedural logic. However, with appropriate use of CTEs (`WITH x AS (...)`) you'd be surprised how much logic you can stuff into a single `SELECT`. This is getting off track, though -- please ask a new question if you want help rewriting your existing function as a TVF.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a SYNONYM to abstract out the schema name.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really two questions:

- Does my function need to have the same schema as the tables it's selecting from? The answer is **no**. `dbo.MyFunction()` can select from `test.MyTable` just fine. However, you may run into issues with ownership chaining -- different schemas mean explicit permissions must exist for the user to select from the table. See [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb669084) for details.
- Can I invoke a function with a parameterized schema, without using dynamic SQL? The answer is **no**. An object name is static -- although SQL does have a "feature" in the form of deferred name resolution that allows you to refer to objects in stored procedures even if they do not exist, this still doesn't allow you to make the schema name variable.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen - you are absolutely correct and correcting me on point one menas I shall be able to create the function as dbo. (taking on baord your comments re: ownership chaining).

Answer (score 0):

I would more so *highly* recommend changing the architecture to be different Servers (ideally--to keep instance/database/schema names the same), else difference Instances (less ideal, but keeps database/schema names the same), or at the very least different Databases (even less ideal, but keeps the schema names the same). Just from a pure coding and testing perspective, you are co-mingling your test and production code and data. It is way to easy to make a mistake and cross schemas for data. And why force production to suffer from performance issues in dev? You can't even backup/restore dev separately. Even if these different schemas are in different databases or servers, from a QA perspective, the code that you are testing in "dev" is *not* the code being deployed to production.

HOWEVER, you can accomplish this without much trickery by making use of different Users. Each user has a default schema. If you had three users: DevUser, TestUser, and LiveUser, each with their respective default schemas, then you would simply *not* use schema names when referencing objects. SQL Server will check the default schema first. This way, each user would get their respective objects.